# Progressbar in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar

[Installed Progressbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKtUo.png)

[But while executing the code it still shows module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeQfi.png)

Comment: Check python version , Pip must have been installed using the python version being used

Comment: Checked EveryThing is the latest version and pip is installed

Comment: To bring more interest in you questions: do not link to "screen shots" provide the information in text form in the question. So the readers do not have to go through multiple clicks to understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Jupyter-notebook you can use this code

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm

for x in tqdm(range(1000000)):  
      pass
```